# JS on iOS device returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, date

Working on a script to block some dates in a calendar.
Trying to block dates by their name(data-picker="2021-7-8"). In Calendar their names are done in format yyyy-mm-dd, which isn't supported in iOS. I can't translate this data to iOS format YYYY/MM/DD because otherwise it won't be found.

```
<td class="current-month" data-picker="2021-7-8">8</td>
```

My code:

```
 let findDate = setAttrDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(setAttrDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+setAttrDate.getDate()                                 
 $('.cal-month td[data-picker="'+findDate+'"]').addClass('pastDay');
```

Comment: The question is not understandable. Where does setAttrDate come from and is it that object that contains NaN? Where is the iOS issue?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not understandable. Where does setAttrDate come from and is it that object that contains NaN? Where is the iOS issue?

This works

```js
// from dashes:

const d = "2021-7-2";
const [yyyy,mm,dd] = d.split("-")
const setAttrDate = new Date(yyyy,mm-1,dd,15,0,0); // normalise at 15:00
console.log(setAttrDate)
let findDate = `${setAttrDate.getFullYear()}-${setAttrDate.getMonth()+1}-${setAttrDate.getDate()}`;
console.log(findDate)
$('.cal-month td[data-picker="'+findDate+'"]').addClass('pastDay');
```

```css
.pastDay { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="cal-month"><tr><td data-picker="2021-7-2">02</td></tr></table>
```